# multiple adjectives next to each other

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, adjectives

> In low volume, a melody sad love song is playing in a mobile phone placed on the side table.

Do you see the three adjectives (melody sad love) together? Is that correct?

Comment: Question assumes facts not in evidence ...

Comment: :) @MετάEd There are no "facts" assumed, only a supposition.

Comment: Someone thought this Q was "too localized" (?!) and wanted it closed.

Answer (score 5):

I see only one adjective.

- *Melody* is a noun. The adjective form would be [*melodious*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/melodious) (or possibly [*melodic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/melody)).
- *Sad* is indeed an adjective describing *love song*.
- *Love* is not an adjective. It is a [noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) — a noun which serves the function of an adjective in the [noun phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase), *love song*.

The use of *melody* as a noun makes this sentence ungrammatical. This would be correct:

> In low volume, a melodious, sad love song is playing in a mobile phone placed on the side table.

Although there are still only two *pure* adjectives, not three.

Comment: On correction, there would be, functionally, three adjectives.

Comment: A 'noun adjunct' is no more than a noun used in a adjectival function, right?

Comment: @Kris: There is a confusion of terminology in the literature here. Those who say 'the _noun adjunct_, though functioning adjectivally, does not actually become an adjective (by conversion) but remains a noun' would probably not accept 'there would be, functionally, three adjectives' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Logic! If it doesn't *remain* a noun, why would we need to say "functioning adjectivally" rather than "being/ becoming an adjective"? It's not an adjective, it's a noun; it serves as an adjective in the context. :)

Comment: I think the adjectival form you want is not *melodic* but *melodious*.

Comment: But there seems to be a rule that noun-adjuncts must be closer to the head noun than any true adjectives. _Traditional farmer_ is fine (adjective) _pig farmer_ is fine (noun adjunct), _traditional pig farmer_ is fine, but _*pig traditional farmer_ is ungrammatical. Furthermore, the possible meanings of noun adjuncts are narrower than adjectives: usually either the kind of object that the head noun uses/refers to/consists of, or which subclass of thing the head noun is. So I can imagine you might classify songs as _word songs_ or _melody songs_. That's the only meaning I can think of for it.

Comment: @StoneyB Can you explain why *melodious* is more appropriate here than *melodic*?

Comment: @p.s.w.g  *Melodic* means 'of' or 'respecting melody'; it would be used in a technical sense, as opposed to *harmonic*. *Melodious* means 'characterized by a pleasing melody' or by 'pleasing music'.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. It seems most dictionaries list one definition of *melodic* that is synonymous *melodious*, and that's how I've typically heard it, but you're right, *melodious* is a better term in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If the essence of the question is whether it is grammatical to chain three adjectives in a row, then the answer is: Yes.

There's nothing ungrammatical or illegal about using any number of adjectives consecutively. However, good writing style recommends that the number of adjectives be limited to three and to avoid using more than two where possible.

Comment: There may be previous questions dealing with the topic, do check out. You may also like to see some standard style guides for useful recommendations.

Comment: +1 Good style recommendation. I'm suddenly reminded of the ["great grey-green, greasy Limpopo River"](http://www.is.wayne.edu/MNISSANI/ELEPHANT/elechild.htm).

Comment: +999 commenter for invoking Kipling.

Comment: The Kipling construction works superbly. The OP's construction seems rather contrived, and a little confusing as _melody_ is usually a noun rather than a noun modifier (or, to use p.s.w.g.'s term, noun adjunct). Style usually requires that ordinary adjectives are placed before any noun modifiers.