# Semicolons -- How many is too many?

Tags: semicolons

In some legal documents, sentences can be the lengths of paragraphs due to semicolons. What are the grammatical rules for the use, or maximum number, of semicolons for non-legal writing?

Here is a specific example I am struggling with: IC; (transitional phrase), IC; IC.

Independent clause = IC.

Does my example use semicolons validly?

Comment: Are you seriously asking us whether the exact text **IC; (transitional phrase), IC; IC.** (with no other context) constitutes enough/too many/too few semicolons? All I can say is the **(transitional phrase),** bit seems somewhat syntactically divorced from anything I can meaningfully attach it to.

Comment: There is no limit to how many semicolons one can use. Punctuation =/= grammar. There is a stylistic guideline, however, which is to use a semicolon when it clarifies meaning and not to use one when it obscures meaning. The same goes for all punctuation.

Answer (score 7):

There are no upper limits on how many semicolons you can use; in fact, there aren't set limits on the number of [adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/multiple-adjectives-next-to-each-other/112681#112681) you can use to describe a noun, or the number of [clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137290/relative-clause-inside-another-relative-clause/137310#137310) that can be attached to another relative clause, either; grammar doesn't normally prescribe such limits; leave it to the legal profession to stretch the boundaries of sensibility, though; yes, your example is valid, although it might be prudent to see whether it wouldn't read better if one of those semicolons were converted to a full stop.

Answer (score 2):

There are no grammatical rules that do what you want.  Sorry.  It may be unwise to use many semicolons because it makes a text less comprehensible, but you can't expect to find a remedy in a grammar.